# Create folders based on second column in text file and then move files into their folders accordingly

Tags: batch-file, directory, command-prompt

I have thousands of files received from a CNC machine to be sorted. I also have an index that lists all the files and their categories. The column is separated by a tab character. Here is the example of content of the index file:

```
111.MAZ      AAA FGH
222.MAZ      BBB IYU
333.EIA      CCCDFEW
444.MAZ      AAAWER BB BBBA
555.EIA      AAA 123
666.M6M      DDD234
777.PBD      AAA
.......      .....
```

Thus, I need to do the following:

1. Create folders based on the second column (successful), using Excel to separate the column, batch create folder using the following command:

for /f %d in (list.txt) do md %d

2. Transfer all my files into their folders accordingly (?)

I'm not sure how to do the second task. Can someone point me in the right direction?

---

After hundred times of running and failing, finally, I have successfully sorted all of them into their respective folders thanks to @Stephan and @JosefZ. I tweaked the code a little bit so that I only create the ones where the file exists.

```
for /F "tokens=1,*" %%G in (index.txt) do (
    IF EXIST %%G (
        md "%%~H" 2^>NUL
        move "%%~G" "%%~H"
    )
)
```

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

no need for Excel. You can parse your index with Batch:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=<TAB>" %%a in (index.txt) do (
  REM create Folder, ignore "Folder exists" error:
  echo md "%%b" 2>nul
  REM move the file: 
  echo move "%%a" "%%b"
)
```

**NOTE**: instead of `<TAB>` insert a Tabulator with your Texteditor (Notepad?)

Remove the `echo`s, if the output is good.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help. But I run your code, but it didn't do anything. See the image: http://s4.postimg.org/oa1xzut4t/run.jpg. Somehow it runs, but no results.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to remove the 'echo'. However, when I did, the error appear: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. Also, the file extension *.MAZ got cut off in the middle.

Comment: You didn't mention, that some files might not exist. `*.MAZ got cut off in the middle` - did you **replace** the string `<TAB>` with a Tabulator? (using`tokens=1,*` without defining delimiters will fail, if any filename contains a space. `delims=<tab>" is more robust.

Comment: Oh, that's what you meant by that. Forgive me I'm total newb in this. Yes, your code works too. Appreciate the effort!!

Answer (score 1):

From command line, supposing that your `index.txt` contains exactly two tab-separated columns
*file name*<kbd>Tab</kbd>*category name*
Operational `md` and `move` commands are merely displayed for debugging purposes; remove all `echo` no sooner than debugged:

```
for /F "tokens=1,*" %G in ( index.txt ) do @echo md "%~H" 2^>NUL & echo move "%~G" "%~H"
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`&`, `2>1` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply!! I definitely will try this out.